# Should fields whose value can be derived from other fields be serialized?

Tags: c#, serialization

Let's say I have a simple class:

```
    [System.Serializable]
    public class MyClass
        {
            public List<int> MyList;
            public int MyListCount; // The number of items in MyList
        }
```

The above is just a (silly) example but since MyListCount can be derived at any time from MyList, should it be serialized (or perhaps ignored)? Why or why not?

Comment: Why would you have MyListCount if MyList.Count already has that?

Comment: To cache some stuff maybe? Or maybe if you MyListCount could be the initial count of the list at initialization. Maybe that would make more sense. This is just an example. Sorry I couldn't think of a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would exclude them from serialization, and use the [OnDeserialized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribe to re-set them.

I like the principle that you only store the 'non-analytical' properties. (I'd also consider designing the class so that the `MyListCount` was a read-only property.)

It's been a long time since I tried using anything but JSON for serialization, so I might be misremembering details...